# AES PIC24F32KA304

Tags: c, encryption, aes, microchip

I can not seem to decipher my message with the AES algorithm that puts a microchip available on their website

```
#if defined(__dsPIC33E__)
    #include <p33exxxx.h>
#elif defined(__dsPIC33F__)
    #include <p33fxxxx.h>
#elif defined(__dsPIC30F__)
    #include <p30fxxxx.h>
#elif defined(__PIC24E__)
    #include <p24exxxx.h>
#elif defined(__PIC24H__)
    #include <p24hxxxx.h>
#elif defined(__PIC24F__) || defined(__PIC24FK__)
    #include <p24fxxxx.h>
#endif

#include "AES.h"

int main(void)
{
    char block[16] = "Hello World!";
    int key[8] = {0x0100,0x0302,0x0504,0x0706,0x0908,0x0B0A,0x0D0C,0x0F0E};

    AESEncrypt((int*)block, key);
    AESCalcDecKey(key);
    AESDecrypt((int*)block, key);
}
```

[image: Problem AES]

Comment: `(int*)block` invokes undefined behavior. Likely not a bug which will surface on most microcontroller compilers, but still bad practice. Speaking of bad practice, using `int` in microcontroller systems is almost always a bad idea. This is known as "sloppy typing". Use `stdint.h` instead.

Comment: Maybe the typed constant is in read-only (or flash) memory?